# How to log parameters instead of placeholders using sqlx with Postgres?

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I'm using [sqlx](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx) for the first time today.

I'm having really hard time understanding my SQL errors because I cannot copy & paste logged queries in my IDE because the parameters are not converted from placeholders.

It prints:

```
SELECT * from players where team_id = $1 AND id = $2
```

but I would like the below instead:

```
SELECT * from players where team_id = 'ABC' AND id = '123'
```

How to do this?

Comment: Instead of suggesting to close, can you please explain why this question is wrong?

Comment: How do you log the queries?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I'm using `tracing_log::LogTracer` with tracing level `info`.

Comment: I'd like to know how to do what you're saying as the problem, can you give a code example?